# How to make code element not go outside pre tag when screen is small?

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```html
<pre><code>
<!-- some code -->
</code></pre>
```

and I'm center it with flexbox. But when the screen is small the code tag go outside the pre-tag. Here is my code:

```css
pre {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    min-width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
code {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

https://codepen.io/jcubic/pen/zYEOovQ

How can I make the pre tag, to always be the same as code, not 100% max?
I've tried to use `float: left` on the flexbox element but I think that float is ignored when using flexbox.

This is probably a common problem, but I was not able to find the question on SO.

**EDIT**: I don't want text wrapping, I want my container to actually contain all the content that is inside.

Comment: **Why** do you have `<code>` inside a `<pre>` in the first place?

Comment: Anyway, the `<code>` element's contents overspill the `<pre>` because _both_ elements have a default style whereby text-wrapping is disabled... which is by-design. So are you absolutely sure you want your `<code>` to wrap?

Comment: @Dai I know that pre don't have text-wrappig. I don't want text wrapping. I want my container to be bigger annd contain what is inside (code).

Comment: @Dai this is the usual use of code and pre. It's used everywhere, example PrismJS https://prismjs.com/

Comment: u can use overflow auto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey so you can use overflow auto, which adds an extra scroolbar and the text doesnt go outside:  I have edited the codepen, but here's the code anyways:

```html
<style> 
pre {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
    justify-content: center;
    min-width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: auto;
}
code {
    display: inline-block;
}
</style>

<pre><code>
&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;
&lt;html lang="pl-PL"&gt;
     &lt;head&gt;
         &lt;meta charset="utf-8"&gt;
         &lt;meta name="description" content=""&gt;
         &lt;meta name="keywords" content=""&gt;
         &lt;title&gt;Tytuł strony&lt;/title&gt;
         &lt;link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"&gt;
     &lt;/head&gt;
     &lt;body&gt;
         &lt;p&gt;To jest paragraf&lt;/p&gt;
     &lt;/body&gt;
&lt;/html&gt;
</code></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use  `border-collapse: separate;`

```css
pre {
    width=100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
  
}
```

```html
<head>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<pre><code>
&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;
&lt;html lang="pl-PL"&gt;
     &lt;head&gt;
         &lt;meta charset="utf-8"&gt;
         &lt;meta name="description" content=""&gt;
         &lt;meta name="keywords" content=""&gt;
         &lt;title&gt;Tytuł strony&lt;/title&gt;
         &lt;link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"&gt;
     &lt;/head&gt;
     &lt;body&gt;
         &lt;p&gt;To jest paragraf&lt;/p&gt;
     &lt;/body&gt;
&lt;/html&gt;
</code></pre>
```